# Online resources that proof that rand() can return 0?

Tags: c++, random

I only found [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/), which says

> Returns a pseudo-random integral number in the range between 0 and RAND_MAX.

But are 0 and `RAND_MAX` included? I need values from 0 to 1 (included), so:

```
rand() / double(RAND_MAX)
```

will works only if `rand()` can also returns `0` and `RAND_MAX`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Returns a pseudo-random integral value between ​`0`​ and `RAND_MAX` (**`0` and `RAND_MAX` included**).

From [cppr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand), emphasize mine.

---

*However*, `rand` is old and bad, as for example described in [this talk](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) by STL. You should use the modern [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) facilities instead, in your case

```
std::uniform_real_distribution(0, std::nextafter(1.,2.));
```

Comment: it's not old and bad. It depends. For cryptographic stuff is absolutely old and bad, I agree. For scientific simulations is bad as well, it could be ok in some scenarios. For randomizing a game AI it's perfectly fine most of the time

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini Even for game AI's, `<random>` has the advantage that its engines have a well-defined range, thread safety, well-defined behavior in general. Even if you want the behavior of `rand` (whatever that means, as it is highly platform dependent), you can get that out of `<random>` in a sensible, platform independent and reproducible way. `rand` is bad for anything but toy programs. Even the standard itself advises against its use, it just has no advantage over `<random>`.